# Can an Eloquent Relationship automatically include its reverse on the child?

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I have an Eloquent (Laravel 5.1) relationship like:

```
class Form extends Model {

  public function fields(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Field');
  }

}

class Field extends Model {

  public function form(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Form');
  }

  public function getFullTitleAttribute(){
    return $this->form->title . ', ' . $this->title;
  }

}
```

I have a several processes that look up a Form, then for each Field, do something with the `full_title` attribute (which depends on the Field's Form), e.g.,

```
$form = Form::first();
foreach($form->fields as $field){
  echo $field->full_title . "\n";
}
```

The problem is that every Field makes a database query to look up the Form, it's a ton of unnecessary traffic.

Is there a way to update the relationships so that the Field object already has an in-memory link to the Form object that brought it into being?

Answer (score 1):

The sloppy solution I'm using is, *everywhere* I use the Form->fields relationship, I explicitly tell the fetched Fields about their Form:

```
$form = Form::first();
foreach($form->fields as $field){
  $field->setRelation('form', $form);  // Saved you a query
  echo $field->full_title . "\n";
}
```

It's more performant, but it doesn't seem very... Eloquent.